# How can I fix an invalid character constant when comparing characters?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.*;

public class StudentWelcome
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter your student login");
        char ident = in.next().charAt(0,1);

        if (ident == '19')
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome Freshman")
        }
        else if (ident == '18')
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome Sophomore")
        }
        else if (ident.equals(17))
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome Sophomore")
        }
        else if (ident.equals)
    }
}
```

I am basically trying to determine what year someone is by input"19johndo" or "17daquanra" and print the correct welcome statement. eclipse shows an error on line 13 that says invalid character constant. What should I do?

Comment: What is `chatAt(0,1)` supposed to do? Are you trying to make a `char` out of the first 2 characters of a `String`? You can't do that. A `char` is **one** character. For the same reason, you cannot do `'19'` or `'18'` or `'17'`, as those are 2 characters.

Comment: Please open of any solid Java tutorial. Read about types (char/String) and comparing string

Comment: check the characters which you are comparing!

Comment: You should read the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and learn what Strings and characters are.  Seriously, those tutorials are designed to help you.  The "Numbers and Strings" tutorial, in particular, will explain the difference between a character and a string.

Answer (score 0):

@VGR is right in the comment above, this is basic "introduction to Java" stuff. But since StackOverflow is a Q&A resource, and this is a Q, I'll provide an A.

There is no `charAt(int, int)` method on a `String`, so that line won't even compile. If you're really interested in the first 2 characters of the input `String`, then use `substring(0, 2)`. That will return a `String`, not a `char` so you'll need to change the type of your `ident` variable. You'll also have to update how you compare `ident` in the `if` statements, since you're trying to compare against a (invalid) `char` literal. But `char`s can't be more than one character, so you need to compare against `String` literals, for example:

```
if (ident.equals("19")) {
```

That will get your code to compile and maybe even work correctly, but it's still not the best way to do what it seems like you're trying to do. But trying to discuss better implementations is beyond the scope of this question.